# Underfitting in Logistic Regression

Tags: regression, logistic, roc

I ran logistic regression on a data of 3700 patients. I have 9 variables and my outcome is presence of a disease or not. I got the regression coefficients and predicted probabilities. When I apply this model on another data set, no matter what I do the area under ROC curve does not go above 56%.

I am assuming there is underfitting in my model. How can I improve this and reduce the high bias? Any way to calculate the bias in a software? How can I fix this underfit in a software?

Thank you very much to anyone who provides a solution.

Comment: What was the AUC for the original model. This sounds more like overfitting than underfitting, but I can't tell from what you've put.

Comment: Since the original data was used to generate the model, AUC is 99.9%

Answer (score 1):

From what you described, it is hard for me to say it is under-fitting. It is even possible over-fitting. I would suggest to use "learning curve" plot to check the problem.

[How to know if a learning curve from SVM model suffers from bias or variance?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/220827/learning-curve-bias-or-variance/220852#220852)

Suppose you verified it is under-fitting. Basis expansion can be used to increase the variance of the model. The basis expansion can be polynomial expansion or spline expansion. Details and examples can be found in

[Why are there large coefficents for higher-order polynomial](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/233414/why-are-there-large-coefficents-for-higher-order-polynomial)

Comment: Thank you very much Sir. Can we still apply learning curves for training and test data when the sample size is different for both?

Comment: @Faiz_Yusufi Yes. I think training and testing does not need to be have same size.

Comment: Ok Sir. I will learn the learning curve and perform it on my data. Can I please have some way to contact you to ask for more assistance and inform about my results?

Comment: @Faiz_Yusufi i do not think that is the way Stack Exchange works. People may busy for other issues and may not want to leave contact info.

Comment: No problem Sir. I will work on my problem and update the progress here. Thank you so much.

Comment: I think my data is overfitting from what the two links explain. So, how do I tackle this problem now? Can I transform my regression coefficients to some suitable value? What is the ideal method to overcome overfitting and in which software?

Comment: @Faiz_Yusufi this post (my another answer) explains how to fix the overfitting on logistic regression. http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/228763/regularization-methods-for-logistic-regression/228785#228785

Comment: Again thank you very much Sir. I will update my progress here once I learn and apply it.

Comment: In my data I have 8 variables and a binary outcome variable for the two data sets. The predicted probabilities of the training data after logistic regression are properly distributed between 0 and 1. While for the test data all the probabilities are either exactly 0 or 1. Can you please explain how and using which variables and software can I plot the learning curve? I do not know the procedure. Thank you.